# C++11 trying to extract a substring using regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

This is my application:

```
// regex_example.cpp:
//  How to compile:
//   $ g++ -std=c++11 regex_example.cpp -o regex_example

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
  std::string input = "Pizza Carrot Lasagna 15000  ";
  std::smatch match;
  std::regex test_reg("[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*");

  if (std::regex_search(input.begin(), input.end(), match, test_reg))
  {
    std::cout << "This is the string found: " << match[1] << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

When I compile it, this is what the compiler shows me:

> regex_example.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: regex_example.cpp:24:68:
>   error: no matching function for call to
>   ‘regex_search(std::__cxx11::basic_string::iterator,
>   std::__cxx11::basic_string::iterator, std::__cxx11::smatch&,
>   std::__cxx11::regex&)’    if (std::regex_search(input.begin(),
>   input.end(), match, test_reg))

Basically, I'm trying to do the following:

1 - Have this compile.  I don't understand why I'm getting the syntax error.

2 - From the input string, I'm trying to extract the number 15000.  I'm assuming that when I get this compiling, I will get a string of 15000.

Comment: What version of g++ are you using?  FWIW `std::regex_search(input.begin(), input.end(), match, test_reg)` can be rewritten as `std::regex_search(input, match, test_reg)` to save on typing.

Comment: Use `if (std::regex_search(input, match, test_reg))` - see https://ideone.com/Rr5c3q

Comment: But *why* does it not work with iterators? It seems that [overload 1 of std::regex_search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) should be applied here.

Comment: @NathanOliver this version: g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I got a similar error when I took your advice: regex_example.cpp:15:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘regex_search(std::__cxx11::string&, std::__cxx11::cmatch&, std::__cxx11::regex&)’

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
std::regex_search(input.begin(), input.end(), match, test_reg)
```

Calls the overload

```
template< class BidirIt, class Alloc, class CharT, class Traits >
bool regex_search( BidirIt first, BidirIt last,
                   std::match_results<BidirIt,Alloc>& m,
                   const std::basic_regex<CharT,Traits>& e,
                   std::regex_constants::match_flag_type flags = 
                       std::regex_constants::match_default );
```

and it requires that the `match_result` to be a `std::match_results<BidirIt,Alloc>`.  In this case that is a `std::string::iterator` but `match`, which is a `std::smatch`, uses a `std::string::const_iterator`.  Since those do not match, the compiler is unable to determine what `BidirIt` should deduce to.

There are many ways you can work around this but the simplest solution is to just use the `std::string` overload like:

```
std::regex_search(input, match, test_reg)
```

([Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8977ee87ec3c4c36))